# ffmpeg - 'No such file or directory' though the file exists

Tags: android, ffmpeg, mobile-ffmpeg

I am running following command to extract audio from videos and merge them into a single file:

```
-y -hide_banner -i /storage/emulated/0/Videos/video_4.mp4 -i /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/VID-20210430-WA0010.mp4 -i /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/VID-20210430-WA0052.mp4 -filter_complex [0:a]atrim=duration=1119.028,volume=1[a_0];[1:a]atrim=duration=84.057,volume=1[a_1];[2:a]atrim=duration=278.029,volume=1[a_2];[a_0][a_1][a_2]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[audio] -map [audio] -acodec aac -vn /storage/emulated/0/Videos/audio.aac
```

But ffmpeg says

```
/storage/emulated/0/Videos/video_4.mp4: No such file or directory
```

I can ensure that the file exist on that specified path. What might cause the issue?

Note: The same error occures for some other comands too, but in all the cases the video file exist in the specified path.

Comment: You might not have read access to the `video_4.mp4` file. Beyond that, if that is the literal command in the first code snippet, you are not quoting the filesystem paths, so the whitespace in `WhatsApp Video` may confuse the command executor, when you get past your first problem.

Comment: I do have read access on that file. This error occurs even for some of the file without whitespace in the path.

Comment: How did you obtain read access? Android version of used device?

Comment: I used runtime permission to obtain read access. Not bounded to any specific android version, but most of them are from API version 28. I can ensure that the file exist and is not read only because just before running this particular command another command executed successfully on the same file.

Comment: Why cannot be the file read only? It is only read i think. Or are you gonna modify it? Isnt ffmpeg a different app that you try to start? If so then it does not have the same permissions.

Comment: Try adding this flag: `-allowed_extensions ALL`.

Comment: @Darkman the exact same command works for most of the cases without the `-allowed_extensions ALL` flag. Can you please explain the reason to use this flag?

Note: I couldn't reproduce the issue in any of my devices, so I cant't verify if your solution works or not for now.

Comment: @MdYeamin Well I'm not really sure if that is going to help you. Sometimes, when I am using ffmpeg for m3u8 files, ffmpeg refuses to do anything because of security issues - and adding that flag helps. I suggest you to add `-loglevel 40` to ffmpeg for more verbose output and always redirect the output into a file.

Comment: @MdYeamin have you got solution?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, I installed it using snap.

So, as a solution, I tried uninstalling using *remove* and *purge*, and then I used `mv /snap/bin/ffmpeg /snap/bin/ffmpeg_old`.

Then I installed using `apt-get install ffmpeg`, and worked. I guess the problem was the version of ffmpeg.